# Android 4.1.2 Unfortunately has stopped

Tags: android-emulator

I want to download and parse an XML code from the internet and I have no problems with the version 2.3.3. Everything runs perfect!

But when I start the version 4.1.2 (AVD) I got following error:

Unfortunately, myProject has stopped.

At this line:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost)
```

What is the problem with version 4.1.2?
I searched for hours in the web, but still have no result.

Comment: guessing, as you did not provide any info about the error: you are doing networking in your main thread, and you shouldn't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: Would you please post the error and some more of the code?